# How does same value zero algorithm works?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, maps

I was going through map chapter in Javascript.info and there is a link given to SameValueZero algorithm. Can someone explain how does that algorithm works in simple words.

I tried going through the link but can't find anything.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/tc39/Array.prototype.includes/#why-samevaluezero) help at all?

Comment: Yeah ! great article thnx :)

Comment: Accept one of your answers, if either of them solved your problem- you will get +2 rep.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero):

> The internal comparison abstract operation SameValueZero(x, y), where x and y are ECMAScript language values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    - If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true.
>    - If x is +0 and y is -0, return true.
>    - If x is -0 and y is +0, return true.
>    - If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    - Return false.
> 3. Return SameValueNonNumber(x, y).

It's basically the same as a `===` test, except that when `x` and `y` are both `NaN`, they pass the test as well. You could implement it like this:

```js
const sameValueZero = (x, y) => x === y || (Number.isNaN(x) && Number.isNaN(y));

console.log(sameValueZero(0, 0));
console.log(sameValueZero(0, 1));
console.log(sameValueZero(0, NaN));
console.log(sameValueZero(NaN, NaN));
```

Comment: Thnx Got it !! :)

Answer (score 2):

[Same value zero comparison](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm ([see here why](https://github.com/tc39/Array.prototype.includes/#why-samevaluezero)), which is a modified version of the [strict equality comparison](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison). The main difference between the two is NaN with NaN equality consideration:

- Same value zero considers that NaN is equal with NaN
- Strict equality considers that NaN is not equal with NaN

Comment: Thnx !! Got it !! :)