# How to distinguish between Array's empty items and undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a Linked List with Array's methods. Currently trying to implement `indexOf` and `includes`. I was looking into the following corner case:

```
var arr = [1,2,,4,5];
console.log(arr.indexOf(undefined));
console.log(arr.includes(undefined));
console.log(arr[2] === undefined);
```

Output:

```
-1
true
true
```

It looks like, for `arr=[1,2,,4,5]` it will actually keep `undefined` at `arr[2]`. Reading ECMA-262 and based on this [page](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/equality), `indexOf` uses "Strict Equality" (operator `===` ) and `includes` uses SameValueZero (Same as `Object.is`, except `-0` is considered equal to `+0`). My functions are:

```
isStrictlyEqual(x,y) {
  return x === y;
}

sameValue(x, y) {
  return Object.is(x,y);
}

sameValueZero(x, y) {
  return x === y || (Number.isNaN(x) && Number.isNaN(y));
}
```

The implementation of `sameValueZero` was taken from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56195369/how-does-same-value-zero-algorithm-works).

My `indexOf` uses this `isStrictlyEqual` and my `includes` uses this `sameValueZero`. But, `sameValueZero(undefined,undefined)` returns `true` so My `indexOf` return index `2` for `indexOf(undefined)` while `arr.indexOf(undefined)` returns `-1`. Note that `[1,2,undefined,4,5].indexOf(undefined)` returns `2`. So my only guess is that Array does not actually store this empty item as `undefined`.

I have a method that allows to fill a linked list from an existing array, like so:

```
  _extend(iterable) {
    for (var i = 0; i < iterable.length; ++i) {
      this.push(iterable[i]);
    }
```

In this case `iterable[2]` will return `undefined` so my DS will save `undefined` at index `2`. Also tried to use `forEach`, but it actually skips the empty items.

I want my linked list to be similar to implementation of Array and follow ECMA specification. How my linked list should treat this corner case? Keeping `undefined` at that place, didn't work because of `indexOf`. I guess I need to distinguish between an empty item and `undefined`. How can I do so? I came across with this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622064/check-the-array-has-empty-element-or-not) - does it mean I need to do two loops on the array? One regular `for` and one `for in`? Would I need to create a dummy node in that case? Does it make sense to do it for Linked list?

My linked list class:

```
class DoublyLinkedList {
  constructor(array=null) {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.length = 0;
    if (array !== null) {
      this._extend(array);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can (have to) add a dummy node and check for it in `includes` (and I guess also `find` and `findIndex`). Here's a POC:

```js
const HOLE = Symbol()

class MyArray {
  constructor() {
    this.items = []
  }

  extend(a) {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      this.items.push(
        a.hasOwnProperty(i) ? a[i] : HOLE
      )
  }

  indexOf(val) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++)
      if (this.items[i] === val)
        return i
    return -1
  }

  includes(val) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++)
      if (Object.is(this.items[i], val) || (val === undefined && this.items[i] === HOLE))
        return true
    return false
  }
}


m = new MyArray()
m.extend([1, 2, 3, , 5])

console.log(m.indexOf(undefined))
console.log(m.includes(undefined))

m = new MyArray()
m.extend([1, 2, 3, undefined, 5])

console.log(m.indexOf(undefined))
console.log(m.includes(undefined))
```